# Migrate Cocos2d-x project from Mac to Ubuntu

Tags: c++, macos, ubuntu, cocos2d-x

I'm developing a game on C++ using Cocos2d-x v3.5. I use latest Xcode and have no problems with make & run. But my friend who wishes help me can't run my project on his Ubuntu. We guess something is wrong with cocos2d make-files (we've found 2 named `CMakeLists.txt` ). Are there any ideas how to fix our makefiles and run project on Ubuntu?

[image: build issuer]

[(full size)](https://pp.vk.me/c623227/v623227952/2aa90/CVTyX0pmJGU.jpg)

P.S. 
Source codes are in private repository but I can provide any additional info

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not the `Makefile`.   The compiler does not know what `USING_NS_CC` means, which implies an error including header files.

If you are using Xcode (which is not clear given you say you "have no problems with make & run") then it's possible that the Cocos2d-x header files are included in the precompiled header file (`prefix.pch`) and therefore don't need to be explicitly `#included` in other files.

However these precompiled headers may not be set-up correctly under Linux/cmake.

The answer is to include the Cocos2d-x header files explicitly in any file that references the Cocos2d-x API.

Comment: it works, now we have a lot of `error: ‘cocos2d’ does not name a type`

Comment: @Vladimir That sounds like the same error; are you sure you are including the header files in those files too?